# How can I leave a blank space/column inside an appended row?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to leave a blank column in between data of an appended row, so that I can add a **VLOOKUP** function, functionally I don't need to do this (I could just add the VLOOKUP to the end of the row), but aesthetically it would be better if I could. Is there a way to just skip a column when appending data into a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

You can use two separate [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) statements to achieve your goal and paste the data right after the last row with content with [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getLastRow()).

- I have fully described each block of lines in the following script so I think it is straightforward to work with it.

I tried to create a generic code where you can select:

- the column you want to separate the data: `sep_col`
- the starting column you want to paste the data: `start_col`
- the number of columns you want to have between the two different datasets: `space_col`

### Code snippet:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  // get spreadsheet details
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // change that to the name of your sheet
  
  // provide some data
  const sep_col = 3; // column you want to separate the data 
  const data = ["d1","d2","d3","d5","d6"];
  const data1 = data.slice(0,sep_col);
  const data2 = data.slice(sep_col,data.length);

  // get current last row of document
  const Lrow = sh.getLastRow();
  
  // paste the data to separate ranges
  const start_col = 1; 
  const space_col = 1;
  sh.getRange(Lrow+1,start_col, 1, data1.length).setValues([data1]); 
  sh.getRange(Lrow+1,start_col+data1.length + space_col, 1, data2.length).setValues([data2]);        
}
```

**JavaScript References:**

[Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

**Sheet used for the code snippet:**

[image: example]